# wordpress site behand load balancer not loading

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a WordPress site that is not loading after passing it through https. The site is hosted in AWS and is behind the load balancer. The domain of the site is registered under an external registerer.
I also have other sites in which the domain is registered with AWS and they are behind the load balancer as well and they load perfectly on https. I am not sure why this one is not loading, the load balancer health check status indicated that it is healthy.

This is what I have on my wp-config.php file

```html
define('WP_HOME','domain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','domain.com');

if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
       $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

Comment: What happens if you go to the Load Balancer's URL (without using your own domain name)? What happens if you go to the WordPress instance directly (without going via the Load Balancer)? How is the Domain Name configured -- is it using an A-Record, a CNAME or something else?

Comment: when i load the page using the load balancer url it is redirected to https://domainname but it does't load the page. load ok without going through the load balancer on http. yes the domain is configure using A-record

Comment: The domain name should be be setup as a CNAME to the URL of the Load Balancer. When accessing the Load Balancer URL, it should be directed to a Target Group, which should point to the WordPress instance, not a domain name.

Comment: That's how it is currently setup.

Comment: When I try to create a CNAME record I can't target alias for the load blancer doesn't show up

Comment: Ah! Okay, if you're an Alias in Route 53, then use an `A-Record`. That is correct.

Comment: This particular domain is with a third party registar. correct. It looks like an issue with SSL cert. Did you configure the SSL certificate in the load balancer.

Comment: Yes the domain is with a third party registerer. The ssl is configured in ALB

Comment: The certificate is setup in ACM then I specify the certificate on the ALB when I created the ALB.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have set the SSL cert for the load balancer. I guess that you are sending the SSL traffic to the ec2 instances. If you send the SSL traffic to the ec2 instances, the instances should have the SSL certificate and decrypt the incoming traffic.

Alternatively, You can choose to terminate the SSL at the load balancer and send the decrypted traffic to the instances.

if you look at the screenshot taken of the ec2 classic load balancer console below, SSL traffic is sent to the instance via port 80.

[image]

Comment: I did that but the page is still not loaded.  I'm just wondering if there's is something that needs to be done at the domain registerer.

Comment: Can you try something. Create CNAME called "test" and point it to the load balancers DNS name. Then access the website using test.yourdomain.com.because I don't think you can point A record to point to load balancer if you are not using Route53 to manage your DNS records.

Comment: Still doesn't load force it to use https. But it loads ok on http

Comment: did you try my suggestion

Comment: Yes, I've try it but it didn't load

Comment: How did you go. Have you figured it out

Comment: I've asked the domain registerer to add the ns record on domain dns records before I can try it again. All the aws registered with aws work fine, just the external one that is giving problem.

Answer (score 0):

I pass the ns records to my external domain registerer to add it on the the dns record, then I try again and it pickup.